# Three.js: First person camera collision detection

Tags: three.js, collision-detection

I have a very simple scenario in Three.js, where the user can move the camera around in order to have a first person perspective.

The camera must not move inside an object, e.g. a cube. I try to prevent that with `Raycaster.intersectObjects`. Hovever, only one face of the cube is recognized when I walk into it. It seems as if the other faces of the cube are not "visible" for the ray, but of course they are perfectly rendered.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(size, size, size, 20, 20, 20);
cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00FF00, wireframe: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide}));
geometries.push(cubeMesh); 

...

var oldCamera;
function moveAround(){
    oldCamera = camera.clone();
    if(movement=="forward") camera.translateZ(-30);
    if(movement=="left") camera.translateX(-30);
    if(movement=="backward") camera.translateZ(30);
    if(movement=="right") camera.translateX(30);
    ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, oldCamera.position.normalize());
    ray.far = 100;
    if(ray.intersectObjects(geometries).length>0){
        // only the case with one of the faces of a cube
        ...
```

**[EDIT 2020.05.09]**

I uploaded a working example on GitHub:

https://github.com/TovAqulic/threejs_collision_issue/blob/master/index.html

You can move (the camera i.e. yourself) around by using the arrow keys and can turn by using the mouse.

All the geometry objects, i.e. the surrounding walls and the block in the middle, are part of the `geometries` array that is checked with `raycaster.intersectObjects(geometries)`.

In almost all cases the movement is blocked when moving onto a wall, by frontal, backward or sideways movement, as expected.

**However, there are positions where you can move through the walls, particularly the walls to the right. E.g., just move to the right wall directly after loading the page.**

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, oldCamera.position.normalize());

This code is not ideal. Create your instance of `THREE.Raycaster` once and then reuse it. Also name it `raycaster` (since it is not an instance of `THREE.Ray`). Besides, before calling `intersectObjects()`, use this code to prepare the raycaster:

```js
raycaster.ray.origin.copy( camera.position );
camera.getWorldDirection( raycaster.ray.direction );
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I cannot test your approach due to errors: My code worked with the old version three.min.js.r59, but this does not support getWorldDirection, so I switched to three.min.js.r116.1, in which getWorldDirection is defined. But when calling raycaster.intersectObjects(geometries) I get an error in three.min.js: TypeError: a.layers is undefined  (line 321). I also get an error with three.js.r116.1 and three.min.js.r110, all after using raycaster.intersectObjects(geometries).

Comment: Do I have to include something else as well?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give a working example as a codepen?

Comment: TBH, it seems more appropriate to me if you share your current progress of work as a codepen. Or maybe as a GitHub repo.

Comment: I understand. But can you tell me what I am missing with my include? Then I can at least post a working version.

Comment: Importing `three.js` should be sufficient in order to run the above code. No additional files are necessary.

Comment: I put a working example on GitHub: https://github.com/TovAqulic/threejs_collision_issue/blob/master/index.html

Comment: I've transferred your code to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ge60jkv2/. However, no runtime error occurs.

Comment: No, but the issue with the collision remains. See my edit above.

Comment: You are not computing the ray's direction vector correctly. You can't just use a normalized position. Instead, you have to compute the direction based on the old and current camera position: https://jsfiddle.net/67twvckL/

Comment: Thanks, but I am still able to "enter" the right wall at some points in that fiddle.

Comment: I can't reproduce. What should I have to input? BTW: Doing this kind of collision detection is not robust anyway. Considering the structure of your maze, using AABB-ABB intersections tests is more promising. Meaning you represent the players as an [ABBB](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3) and the cubes and then use [Box3.intersectsBox()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.intersectsBox).

Comment: I just move to the "right" wall and incrementally check if I can move inside. It works at some point.

Comment: Can you change your answer and explain why it is not a robust solution and that (why/how) one should use AABB-ABB intersections tests? I will accept your answer.

Comment: No sorry. I've already invested enough time in this thread. I suggest you search in the `three.js` forum for more information about this topic. E.g. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-add-collision-with-raycast/11545/2?u=mugen87

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help!